# Problems solving a differential equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a differential equation:

$dN/dt = a*N*(90-N)$  with $N(0)=3$ and $N(11)=43$:

Using:

```
DSolve[{n'[t] == a*n[t]*(90 - n[t]), n[0] == 3}, n[t], t])
```

I get:

> ```
> {{n[t] -> (90 E^(90 a t))/(29 + E^(90 a t))}}
> ```

but when I try to solve this equation:

```
Solve[3870/(43 + 47 E^(990 a)) == 3, a] //N
```

I get this result:

> ```
> {{a -> ConditionalExpression[0.0010101 (3.27835 + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

Am I inputting something incorrectly or do I need to use another function for this problem?

Comment: I don't think those 2 boundary conditions are compatible with the solution to the differential equation. You can just add the n[11]==43 into the DSolve and you can see it will return nothing.

Comment: Executing `Solve[((90 E^(90 a t))/(29 + E^(90 a t)) /. t -> 11) == 43, a]` gives `a -> ConditionalExpression[1/990 (2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[1247/47]), 
  C[1] \[Element] Integers]`. Presumably you want the real branch of this expression, so appending `C[1]->0` gives `a -> 1/990 Log[1247/47]`.

Comment: @user29165: The two boundary conditions are compatible because he is leaving `a` undefined, including the left boundary condition, and then solving for the value of `a` which satisfies the right boundary condition.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus thanks, I think you are right, how do I input your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, and you just need to be aware of the fact that the inverse of `Exp` is a multi-branched complex function. Presumably you want a real solution, and so you must choose `C[1]` so that the resulting solution is real-valued.

In more detail, you compute the solution with the left boundary condition, and then solve for the value of `a` which also satisfies the right boundary condition:

```
s = DSolveValue[{n'[t] == a*n[t]*(90 - n[t]), n[0] == 3}, n[t], t];
Solve[(s /. t -> 11) == 43, a]
```

giving

```
{{a -> ConditionalExpression[1/990 (2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[1247/47]), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

This is complex-valued except when `C[1] = 0`, so we just do the substitution:

```
% /. C[1] -> 0
```

giving

```
{{a -> 1/990 Log[1247/47]}}
```

You can verify this is correct by the following:

```
g = s /. a -> 1/990 Log[1247/47]
g /. t -> 0
g /. t -> 11
```

which gives

```
3
43
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, what does the c[1] stand for?

Comment: @ChristianBillPedersen: When `Solve`ing for `a` in the second step, you must take the inverse function of `Exp`. In Mathematica, `Log` is the principal branch of the inverse function of `Exp` in the complex plane, with a branch cut discontinuity along $(-\infty,0)$. However, when `Solve` does it, it allows for all possible choices of inverse branch, and thus there is an undetermined integer parameter `C[1]`. The principal branch corresponds to `C[1] = 0`, so making that substitution gives the answer that you are probably looking for. For more info, check out a course in complex analysis.

Comment: @ChristianBillPedersen You can also just use `Solve[(s /. t -> 11) == 43, a, Reals]`, to specify solving over the reals.